# simulate random variable from pdf (discrete case)

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, matlab

I am trying to simulate n random discrete variable which has the following 
pmf

$P(X = k) = (1-p)^2kp^{k-1}$

I am thinking about using the inverse transform sampling method and I am trying to find the cdf.

$P(X \le k) = 1 - P(X > k) = 1- P(X \ge k+1) = \sum_{x=k+1}^{\infty} (1-p)^2xp^{x-1} = 1-[ (1-p)^2\sum_{x=k+1}^{\infty}xp^{x-1}]$

= $1-(1-p)^2[(k+1)p^k + (k+2)p^{k+1}+ (k+3)p^{k+2} + ...] $

What I have done so far :

Let $S = (k+1)p^k + (k+2)p^{k+1}+ (k+3)p^{k+2} + ...$

$pS =$       $(k+1)p^{k+1} + (k+2)p^{k+2}+ (k+3)p^{k+3} + ...$

then $(1-p)S = kp^k +p^k + p^{k+1} + p^{k+2}+p^{k+3}+...$
(geometric series )

$(1-p)S = kp^k + \frac{p^k}{1-p}$

$ F(x) = 1- (xp^x(1-p) + p^x)$

Then I'm trying to find the inverse :

$1- (xp^x(1-p) + p^x) < U \le 1- ((x+1)p^{x+1}(1-p) + p^{x+1})$

$xp^x(1-p) + p^x < 1-U < (x+1)p^{x+1}(1-p) + p^{x+1}$

I'm stuck here ...

Any help or hint will be appreciated !

Comment: I do not think there is a nice inverse for the CDF. For discrete random variable, as the CDF is just a step function, you may simply do a summation of the pmf to obtain that, and use that to generate. For example, in your case the support is $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$, you generate $U \sim \text{Uniform}(0, 1)$, then check: If $U < f_X(1)$, where $f_X$ is the pmf of $X$, then assign $X$ = 1. Else check if $U < f_X(1) + f_X(2)$, then assign $X = 2$, and so on. The speed is not too bad if $f(x)$ is mainly dominated in the first few terms, and the tail rapidly converge.

Comment: I guess I have no choice

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can randomly sample from a discrete distribution, unfortunately inverting the CDF is not one of them. The plot below was generated using the [Alias Method](http://keithschwarz.com/darts-dice-coins/), it is particularly efficient if you know how to use binary search trees, otherwise a simple implementation of `argmin`, `argmax` will work

[image]

The blue bars are a histogram of $400$ samples generated with the alias method, the red points are simply

$$
P(X = x) = (1 - p)^2 x p^{x - 1}
$$